# Plural of double barrelled surnames

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the correct plural for double-barrelled surnames: is it "the Scott Fitzgeralds" or the "Scotts Fitzgerald"?

Comment: Usually *"the Scott-Fitzgeralds"* i think.

Answer (score 1):

Scott-Fitzgeralds.

When there is no obvious principle word in a compound noun, you pluralize at the end.